# How do i avoid IOS storyboard seque loop

Tags: ios

My iOS app starts with 2 login screens, then a main "List of accounts" screen. In storyboard I do:

1. Show "Enter User Reg No" View Controller. (VC1)
2. Modal Seque to "Enter PAC digits a,b,c". (VC2)
3. Then Modal Seque to account list. (VC3)

VC3 has a "Logout" button which Modal Seques to VC1.

This is a customer demo prototype. I know it's not correct, as I am building up a loop of VC1,VC2 and VC3s.

What is the correct approach to this? I've read Apple's seque docs, and I still can't find a convincing answer.

Comment: im think its not bad to have a loop like that, another way you can use a navigation controller so user can stap back on previous controller

Answer (score 3):

The best approach to this would be to use a Navigation Controller with push segues (you can keep the navigation bar hidden if you don't need it), then in your logout button IBAction you just put:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

In order to use a Navigation Controller, you just select your VC1 and then select

Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller

Edit: I should also probably point out that they're called seGue, with a "g", not seQue!

Comment: @micantox LOL, thanks! You know, I did know it is segue, it seems to be some kind of learned typing sequence that I type "que" as a block. I've built the code as per your suggestion. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any segue to go from a Modal View back to VC1. Just dismiss the modal view:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Usually there's only one modal view. If you must use two, dismiss them both to go back to VC1